# XAML: setup property from parent view?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have button custom view:

```
<UserControl>
...
<Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" Style="{DynamicResource HighlightStyle}"/>
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Highlight" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
...
</UserControl>
```

And button is used in parent view like next:

```
<local:MyButton x:Name="Btn1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Btn1}" />
```

So when I need button to be highlighted I'm doing this from code. Like `Btn1.IsHighlighted=true;`
But at some point I need to setup this directly from parent XAML. Is it possible?

I.e. on some specific view I don't want `Btn1.IsHighlighted` to be used. Instead I want something like this:

```
<local:MyButton x:Name="Btn1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Btn1}" IsHighlighted="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register the IsHighlighted as an property of your MyButton class

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighlightedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "IsHighlighted",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyButton),
    new PropertyMetadata((bool)false)
);

public bool IsHighlighted
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(IsHighlightedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsHighlightedProperty, value); }
}
```

EDIT adding XAML use

Your MyButton XAML should have something like this

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" Width="100">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

I actually tested Property="Fill" and Value="Green" here. But changed to match your case.

The parent view should have

```
<local:MyButton x:Name="Btn1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Btn1}" IsHighlighted="true" />
```

Comment: Then how the DataTrigger's binding should look? Because now it doesn't work for me with Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted}"

Comment: Where was your IsHighlighted property defined before? Which class is set as DataContext?

Comment: It's in MyButtonModel class... So if there is another model class in use, your solution will not work?